# Adding formula to Vba

Tags: formula

I want to add this formula =MID(C2,SEARCH("",C2)+10,SEARCH("+",C2)-SEARCH("",C2)-10) to the end of formatting code so that it populates column "d" down to the last row
The code i created from record macro:

```
sub Update()
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("C:H").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("E:AK").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Times"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Room"
Columns("G:G").Select
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("K:L").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("M:X").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("N:Q").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Cells.Select
Range("H1").Activate
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("A1:P40").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$P$40"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Outcome"
End Sub
```

This code works really well in formatting the excel sheet I have but I would like to go that one step further and include this little bit of code, however the number of rows varies but will rarely exceed 40

I'd be really appreciate some help or/and advice, thank you in anticipation

Comment: you can do this using the macro recorder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this just before `End Sub`. Because you are have a table formatted already, it will automatically fill in each cell.

```
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],SEARCH("""",RC[-1])+10,SEARCH(""+"",RC[-1])-SEARCH("""",RC[-1])-10)"
```